# Getting error while adding custom model in amp file

Tags: alfresco

I want to add custom model in AMP file but getting following error -

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xyz.dictionaryBootstrap' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/xyz/context/service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 05050000 Could not find bootstrap model config/alfresco/module/xyz/models/xyzContentModel.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)`

Error indicates `xyzContentModel.xml` is missing from path given in `model-context.xml`, but i have double checked and in amp file, `xyzContentModel.xml` is at given path.

I am using Alfresco 4.0d version on Windows X64

Comment: did you check the location of the model in the AMP or in the final WAR file?

Comment: I have checked location in AMP file and it is as given in xml, how to check location in war file?

Comment: you have to install the AMP, either using [maven](code.google.com/p/maven-alfresco-archetypes/) or the [MMT](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Module_Management_Tool) directly. This explodes the AMP into the Alfresco WAR, after which you can look for the file (e.g. `unzip -l alfresco.war | grep xyzContentModel.xml`)

Comment: I don't think you want the leading `config/` on the path when you reference that file, as IIRC it gets stripped from the path on installation. Can you try without that?

Comment: Also check that the model file is well-formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies,

Problem was in the `model-context.xml` file, problem solved by removing `config` from the path of xyzContentModel.xml

Changed path of xyzContentModel.xml in model-context.xml from

`config/alfresco/module/com.diipl.percept.alfresco/models/PerceptContentModel.xml`

to

`alfresco/module/com.diipl.percept.alfresco/models/PerceptContentModel.xml`